# spring-cloud-dataflow OAUTH2 roles and permissions

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to setup Oauth with scdf 2.9.2 and I am at the point where I am able to get the ID-token with the authorization_code grant type. But my user has no roles, in the token our roles are under an attribute called att_member

Is there a way to tie this property to the user?

looking in spring boot config it seems that the roles come from scopes. I have not been able to add these roles to the scope

Comment: Have a look at authorities mapping configuration. Details depend on you application being configured as an OAuth2 client or an OAuth2 resource server.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation on configuration and customization of OAuth2 in Spring Cloud Data Flow. 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-oauth2
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-customizing-authorization

Hopefully there is a property in Spring Security you can set to determine where to find the roles.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html

Which IdP are you using?

Comment: The IdP is called ping. Ive been looking for a spring property I can set to determine the roles, so far no luck. The default is definitely scopes as I have been able to use the scdf role mapping ...ROLE_VIEW=openid and it shows that role available. But of course everyone will have that scope